# Android material design animation

Tags: android, android-animation, material-design

I'm looking to have an animation that transitions a `TextView` with a circle background to a rectangular header. Right now I'm just using the built in animation:

```
String transitionName = getString(R.string.my_transition);
ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,
                myTextView, transitionName);
startActivity(detailIntent, options.toBundle());
```

This works, but the animation isn't that smooth, when I transition back the rectangle header goes to a square that represents the textview and then creates the circle background. I would like to use [this animation](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/v_2/material_ext_publish/0B08MbvYZK1iNT2dLWHE1NG8tV00/animation-meaningfultransitions-consistentchoreography-do1_large_xhdpi.webm) from the Material Design site. I'm not sure if this code is already provided by Google or some other source. If not, I have never made my own animation before so what would be a good tutorial on creating this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check these out :

1. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/825739/Article-Beginners-Guide-to-Android-Animation-Gr
2. [Morph a retangler view into a circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20051829/morph-a-retangler-view-into-a-circle)

These are the interpolators available in android :

```
AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator

@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator

AccelerateInterpolator

@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator

AnticipateInterpolator

@android:anim/anticipate_interpolator

AnticipateOvershootInterpolator

@android:anim/anticipate_overshoot_interpolator

BounceInterpolator

@android:anim/bounce_interpolator

CycleInterpolator

@android:anim/cycle_interpolator

DecelerateInterpolator

@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator

LinearInterpolator

@android:anim/linear_interpolator

OvershootInterpolator

@android:anim/overshoot_interpolator
```

This is how you can create an animator or just an anim using resource/animator or resource/anim respectively.

```
<set
  android:ordering=["together" | "sequentially"]>

    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="string"
        android:duration="int"
        android:valueFrom="float | int | color"
        android:valueTo="float | int | color"
        android:startOffset="int"
        android:repeatCount="int"
        android:repeatMode=["repeat" | "reverse"]
        android:valueType=["intType" | "floatType"]/>

    <animator
        android:duration="int"
        android:valueFrom="float | int | color"
        android:valueTo="float | int | color"
        android:startOffset="int"
        android:repeatCount="int"
        android:repeatMode=["repeat" | "reverse"]
        android:valueType=["intType" | "floatType"]/>

    <set>
        ...
    </set>
</set>
```